# jQuery $.post form data undefined

Tags: jquery, post

I have this code:

```
var d = [];
$('.sortable li').each( function() {
    var book_id = $(this).attr('book-id');
    var order = $(this).index() + 1;
    d.push({'book_id': book_id, 'order': order});
});
console.log(d);
$.post('/books/reorder', d, function(resp) {
    alert(resp);
});
```

When I do `console.log(d);` everything looks great but when I post it to my server the request form data is empty.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the actual request that is being sent in your browser tools or Fiddler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) state that data only takes PlainObject or String

```
Type: PlainObject or String
A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
```

You are trying to send over an array.  You can pass it over if you make it an object

```
$.post('/books/reorder', {data:d},function(resp) {
```

If you read [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation on the data property

```
data
Type: PlainObject or String
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. 
It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic
processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes 
multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
```

The important part is `Object must be Key/Value pairs.`